# User getting null when refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, local-storage

I am new to React and Stack overflow too. If I am making a mistake sorry for that.

When I am logged in and redirect to the home page user is retrieved from the local storage successfully.

[Image: User retrieving successfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUoyc.png)

But when I am trying to redirect to another page or refresh the page, first user gets null, after that user retrieved. Why is that and how can I get user from the first attempt.

[Image: console log user getting null.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjKnR.png)

These are codes I used.

AuthContext.js

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const authReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOGIN":
      return { user: action.payload };
    case "LOGOUT":
      return { user: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(authReducer, {
    user: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

    if (user) {
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: user });
    }
  }, []);

  console.log("AuthContext state:", state);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ ...state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

useAuthContext.js

```
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export const useAuthContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (!context) {
    throw Error("useAuthContext must be used inside an AuthContextProvider");
  }

  return context;
};
```

useLogin.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useAuthContext } from "./useAuthContext";

export const useLogin = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(null);
  const { dispatch } = useAuthContext();

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    setError(null);

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/api/user/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setError(json.error);
    }
    if (response.ok) {
      // save the user to local storage
      localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(json));

      // update the auth context
      dispatch({ type: "LOGIN", payload: json });

      // update loading state
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  return { login, isLoading, error };
};
```